# Jupyter notebook ValueError: Unable to configure formatter 'console'

Tags: jupyter-notebook, virtual-environment, djongo

I installed Django in a virtual environment. However, the nb_conda gets an error in another virtual env.

I tried to reinstall the nb_conda, and the error message output is:

```
Enabling: nb_conda
- Writing config: /home/run/.miniconda3/envs/d2l/etc/jupyter
    - Validating...
      nb_conda 2.2.1 OK
Exception ignored in: <function Application.__del__ at 0x7fa35ad9c3a0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/run/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 955, in __del__
  File "/home/run/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 945, in close_handlers
  File "/home/run/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py", line 683, in __get__
  File "/home/run/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py", line 657, in get
  File "/home/run/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py", line 1428, in _notify_observers
  File "/home/run/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 273, in _observe_logging_default
  File "/home/run/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 278, in _configure_logging
  File "/home/run/.miniconda3/envs/d2l/lib/python3.8/logging/config.py", line 808, in dictConfig
  File "/home/run/.miniconda3/envs/d2l/lib/python3.8/logging/config.py", line 545, in configure
ValueError: Unable to configure formatter 'console'
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is a traitlets defect:

https://github.com/ipython/traitlets/issues/722

That has been solved using patch 727

https://github.com/ipython/traitlets/pull/727

So updating traitlets may solved the issue

It did for I when trying to enbale jupytext:

`jupyter serverextension enable jupytext`

was showing the same error, doing
`mamba/conda update traitlets` solved the issue by updating traitlets from 5.2 to 5.3